# How to animate multiple entries using react native reanimated v2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am new to `reanimated`. I am now trying to reanimating multiple items.

These items will not show up at the start of the component on load.
But they items will show up when the corresponding item is pressed that my intentions.

`eg when button 1 is pressed item 1 will pop up slowly, button 2 is pressed and item 2`
like that.

I got 2 component in my app

`ItemsList screen` and `item component`

I don't have any animation code in itemList screen. I am just retuning the item component.

```
{items.map(item => (
          <OtherItem
            key={item._id}
            item={item}
            selectedItem={selectedItem}
            setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem}
          />
        ))}
```

Inside the item component.I got a `sharedValue, useEffecthooks, and useState` which I use to animate according to user interaction.

**ITEM COMPONENT**

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
    
  // Animation
  const progress = useSharedValue(0);

  const reAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      opacity: progress.value,
      transform: [{scale: progress.value}],
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    progress.value = withTiming(1, {duration: 2000});
  }, [selected]);



return (
    <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => selectItem(item)}
          style={[
            globalStyle.pageContainer,
          ]}>
            {selected && (
                    <Animated.View
                      style={[
                        {flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'},
                        reAnimatedStyle,
                      ]}>
                      ...
                    </Animated.View>
                  )}
        </TouchableOpacity>)
```

As you can see in the code, My intention is that when user press `button 1` hidden details inside `button 1` will show up.

But the thing Is **only the first time works**. I think its because of the `shared value`. What I want is I want every item to work. So can any one suggest the solution

Comment: where is "button 1"?
can you provide more code? or better if you provide with working code in expo snack.

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN I am mapping the `buttons`. I mean `ITEM COMPONENT` itself is the button and there are some hidden text inside each button

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of many solutions.

Track the selected item on "ItemsList screen" using the following snippet

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  const handleSelection = (id) => setSelectedId(id);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {ITEMS.map((item) => (
        <OtherItem
          key={item._id}
          item={item}
          handleSelection={handleSelection}
          selectedId={selectedId}
        />
      ))}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

on "ITEM COMPONENT" screen, use ***useEffect*** to change ***progress.value***. If the "ITEM COMPONENT" sees that the current rendered item is selected then it will increase the ***progreass.value*** 1 other wise it will decrease it to 0.
use the following snippet

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedId === item._id)
      progress.value = withTiming(1, { duration: 2000 });
    else progress.value = withTiming(0, { duration: 2000 }); // un comment this line if you want to see hidden element of just one item and hide the other item
  }, [selectedId]);
```

also send a function ( *handleSelection* in this example ) from "ITEM LIST screen" to "ITEM COMPONENT" screen to track which item is selected.

Here is a expo [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pieamo/animate-mapped-items) with full source code.